# BottomNavigationView menu item title not showing when inactive [XML]

Tags: android, xml

now : https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgdaa.png

I have a bottom navigation bar. Case: the text of bottom navigation bar item menu is not showing when the tab inactive. Text only shows when the tab is active.
What should to show the icon title even when the tab menu is inactive?

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            android:theme="@style/BottomNavigationTheme"
            app:menu="@menu/menu"/>
```

And the styles :

```
    <style name="BottomNavigationTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/tabActive</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/tabInactive</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: please also add @style/BottomNavigationTheme

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[This](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/BottomNavigationView#setlabelvisibilitymode) is the method you're looking for.

Or in XML,

```
app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 5):

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/LabelVisibilityMode) you can see:

> **LABEL_VISIBILITY_AUTO**
>   Label behaves as "labeled" when there are **3 items or less**, or "selected" when there are 4 items or more.

In your screenshot you have 4 labels, so the inherited visibility is **LABEL_VISIBILITY_SELECTED**

You need to set visibility mode as **labeled**. Do it directly from the XML:

```xml
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            android:theme="@style/BottomNavigationTheme"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            app:menu="@menu/menu"/>
```